# Can I create a SQL view to show "fake" data

Tags: sql, sql-server

My boss wants me to create a view in SQL to show data that isn't there. Is that possible? Here's what I need:

I need to show our internal currency conversion rate for any sourceCur that = targetCur. We only have this data for the year 2011, period 1. I need it to show all 12 periods for every year from 2011 to 2017. The value will always be the same (1). Here are the columns yearNum, preiodNum, sourceCur, targetCur, convRate.

A simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CurrencyConversionRates
WHERE (sourceCur = targetCur)
```

The results are:

[image: Results]

The value of convRate will always be 1 in this case because the currency is the same. I just need to project the data we have (2011 period 1) to all 12 periods for each year from 2011 to 2017. My boss does not want to add the data into the table, he wants a view.

Is this possible?

**EDIT FROM COMMENTS**

```
WITH future( yearNum , periodNum) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CalendarYear , 
        fiscalPeriodNum 
    FROM 
        CALENDAR 
    WHERE CalendarYear BETWEEN 2011 AND YEAR(GETDATE())), 

currencies( sourceCur , targetCur) AS ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        sourceCur , 
        targetCur 
    FROM 
        CurrencyConversionRates 
    WHERE targetCur = sourceCur)

SELECT 
    f.yearNum , 
    f.periodNum , 
    c.sourceCur , 
    c.targetCur , 
    '1' AS conversionRate 
FROM 
    future AS f 
CROSS JOIN currencies AS c 
ORDER BY 
    f.yearNum , 
    f.periodNum;
```

Comment: Try using `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE(convRate, 1)`...

Comment: Look up a tally / numbers table. Also, it's always good to have a [Calendar Table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) that you can use for joins like this

Comment: What about the sourceCur and targetCur, are these fixed values or you might have more?

Comment: Add `CROSS JOIN (VALUES (2011),(2012),(2013),(2014),(2015),(2016),(2017)) as years(num)` or use Reqursive CTE to get `years` table

Comment: Those values are fixed to just those 4 currencies.

Comment: select * from cnn

Comment: Got it... it's too long to post what I did

Comment: WITH future(
    yearNum
  , periodNum)
       AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT 
           CalendarYear
         , fiscalPeriodNum
       FROM CALENDAR
       WHERE CalendarYear BETWEEN 2011 AND YEAR(GETDATE())),
       currencies(
    sourceCur
  , targetCur)
       AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT 
           sourceCur
         , targetCur
       FROM CurrencyConversionRates
       WHERE targetCur = sourceCur)

Comment: SELECT 
           f.yearNum
         , f.periodNum
         , c.sourceCur
         , c.targetCur
         , '1' AS conversionRate
       FROM future AS f
              CROSS JOIN currencies AS c
       ORDER BY 
           f.yearNum
         , f.periodNum;

Answer (score 0):

Use a numbers CTE:

```
with CTE as
(
select 1 as NN
union all
select NN +1
where NN < 12
)
, CTE2 as
(
select 2011 + NN as N_Year
from CTE
where NN + 2011 < 2017
)
, CTE3 as
(
select C2.N_Year, C1.NN as N_Month
from CTE2 C2
cross join CTE C1
)

select C3.*, [OTHER STUFF]
from CTE3 C3
left join [Other table] OT
on OT.TheYear = C3.N_Year
and OT.TheMonth = C3.N_Month
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something somewhat similar.... you can see it in my comments above.